# Ensure property existence

Tags: typescript

Right now I'm using this helper-function `nameOf` to get an object's property name as string, **ensuring it actually exists**.

```
export const nameOf = <T extends {}>(name: Extract<keyof T, string>): string => name;

class MyObject {
  propA: string;
  propB1: string;

  func(){
    const propAName = nameOf<MyObject>('propA');

    //I get a compile-time error here - that's what I want to achive without needing a helper-function
    const propBName = nameOf<MyObject>('propB');
  }
}
```

The drawback of this solution is, that the function actually runs on the client / gets compiled. I'm looking for a typesafe way getting an object's property name as string (maybe utilizing the new `satisfies` operator?) but I just don't have a clue.

Here is a minimal repro: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-clu5vs?file=index.ts). I want to get rid of the `nameOf` function that currently (correctly) stops me from setting `const propBName = nameOf<MyObject>('propB');`

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://netbasal.com/create-a-typed-version-of-simplechanges-in-angular-451f86593003).

Comment: Thank you! That's a neat solution for this scenario. But I have other cases, where I actually need a propertys name (e.g. making its value persistent in storage). So I'd still like to find a way to ensure a properties name.

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can just copy and paste into our own IDEs to get started.  Right now it's pseudocode and/or missing declarations so I just get a bunch of errors, and I'm less inclined to work on this if I have to fight my way through that stuff first.

Comment: Please share the code on this site, not only on another site that people may not be able to get to. Questions should be self-contained. See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: You can always check for the existence of a property with the `in` operator (as long as the compiler knows the target is a non-null object type) because this is required for interop with untyped JS. So there's no way to make it complain about that as long as you're writing it that way. One way to handle this would be to use a variable, class static property, or enum member instead of the magic string "prop", but without more info about what you're actually trying to accomplish here I can't say how appropriate that would be.

Comment: "I actually need a propertys name (e.g. making its value persistent in storage)" that implies the value is coming from somewhere else, i.e. it's dynamic (whether storage in this case is localStorage, fetch call, database query: it doesn't matter). It's not even *logically* possible to statically verify the value at compile-time! You will need runtime checks for dynamic data, period.

Comment: I think the word you mean to say is "updated" not "adopted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to ensure that the value of a const is the key of an object you can simply do:

```
const x: keyof MyObject = 'propA'
const y: keyof MyObject = 'propB' // error
```

But I saw the post before the edit so it might not be what you are actually searching for. In case you want to check if an object contains the key of another one I suggest you to create a function like this:

```
const containsKey = <T>(keyToSearch: keyof T, object: { [key: string]: any }) =>
  Object.keys(object).some((key) => key === keyToSearch);

const objectReceived = {}

containsKey<MyObject>('propB', objectReceived) //error since propB is missing
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That even brought me to the idea utilizing `satisfies`, being able to compare the value in a single line: `if (('propA' satisfies keyof SelectInputComponent) in changes) { }`